# Insert huge list contain multiple linked table to database using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sqlbulkcopy

I tried to insert a list contain multiple linked table to the database using `SqlBulkCopy`. After I added the data to the database I discovered that the links between table no longer exist.

Here are the classes:

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblStudentCourses> tblStudentCourses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblTeachers> tblStudentCourses { get; set; }
    }

    public class tblStudentCourses
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int studentId {get;set}
        public string courseName {get;set}
    }
    public class tblTeachers
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int studentId {get;set}
        public string teacherName {get;set}
    }


List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
```

This is the method that I am using to insert the list in the database:

```
var allStudent = student.Select(x=> new {x.id,x.name,x.email,x.phoneNumber});
var studentCourses = student.SelectMany(x => x.tblStudentCourses.Select(y => new {x.id,x.studentId,x.courseName}))
```

For each of the above query I call this `SqlBulkCopy` extension:

```
public static DataTable AsDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = propertyDescriptorCollection[i];
                Type type = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType;

                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                    type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);


                dataTable.Columns.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, type);
            }
            object[] values = new object[propertyDescriptorCollection.Count];
            foreach (T iListItem in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = propertyDescriptorCollection[i].GetValue(iListItem);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Result in Database

```
Student :
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|      id             |     name         |  email     |.....
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          1          |    Johnny        | me@me.com  |       
|---------------------|------------------|------------|


Course :
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|      id             |     studentId    | courseName |     
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          1          |    0             |  JAVA      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Step 1 : Add Newtonsoft package

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Step 2: Convert a list to JSON and after JSON to data table without foreach loop.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
DataTable dtt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

Step 3: After creating a user-defined table in a stored procedure and passed multiple data table to SQL.

Comment: if any issue Johnny then tell me

Comment: DataTable dtt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);

Comment: Have you proper convert list to json.                                                                                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst); lst is your list and check json string comes or not.

Comment: Please see my another answe.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example for the list to data table convert without foreach loop.

```
 public class Friend
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
        }

 List<Friend> lst = new List<Friend>();
            lst.Add(new Friend{ id = 1});
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 1 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 2 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 3 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 3 });
            lst.Add(new Friend { id = 4 });
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
            DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

Comment: **Here how data it look like**

 [ {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "ECO-AFRIQUE SARL",
    "email": "",
    "phoneNumber": "+2396684",
    "tblStudentCourses": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "studentId": 0,
        "courseName": "java"
      }
    ],
    "tblTeachers": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "studentId": 0,
        "teacherName": "Nicole"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]

Comment: but i am still getting **Unexpected JSON token while reading DataTable: EndArray** when i convert from json to data table

Comment: Please pass list spearately (tblStudentCourses,tblTeachers,anothermodel) after it's create three datatable and all datatable pass to sql.

Comment: what do you mean ? i should create three list and pass each list in var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst1);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst2);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst3);